# Newtonsoft Json used inside WPF Form of an Outlook Add-in does not find Application Configuration

Tags: c#, configuration, json.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I've created an Outlook Add-in with Visual Studio 2013 for Outlook 2010 - 2016.
The Outlook Add-in contains 2 WPF Forms which utilize a REST api and do http rest calls. The result is Json and would be deserialized with Newtonsoft Json.

In the debug mode everything works just fine.
As soon as I create the Setup Tool with wix and install the Add-in I got the problem that Json Objects don't get deserialized anymore. The reason for this is that the add-in doesn't find the configuration file.
I have figured out that Outlook looked for the outlook.exe.config in the Office Outlook Program path. But this is not what I want because I don't want to do any changes in that central config file which might affect other applications.

After figuring out this, I found this neat little code snippet to change the config file at the startup of my add-in:

```
 using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public abstract class AppConfig : IDisposable
{
    public static AppConfig Change(string path)
    {
        return new ChangeAppConfig(path);
    }

    public abstract void Dispose();

    private class ChangeAppConfig : AppConfig
    {
        private readonly string oldConfig =
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE").ToString();

        private bool disposedValue;

        public ChangeAppConfig(string path)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", path);
            ResetConfigMechanism();
        }

        public override void Dispose()
        {
            if (!disposedValue)
            {
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", oldConfig);
                ResetConfigMechanism();


                disposedValue = true;
            }
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private static void ResetConfigMechanism()
        {
            typeof(ConfigurationManager)
                .GetField("s_initState", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                         BindingFlags.Static)
                .SetValue(null, 0);

            typeof(ConfigurationManager)
                .GetField("s_configSystem", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                            BindingFlags.Static)
                .SetValue(null, null);

            typeof(ConfigurationManager)
                .Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(x => x.FullName ==
                            "System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths")
                .First()
                .GetField("s_current", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                       BindingFlags.Static)
                .SetValue(null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

After changing the application config to the correct path I can read all Settings out of the config file via System.Configuration.ConfgurationManager (I've tried it at runtime after installing the release version and wrote it out to a file stream).

But Still... when trying to deserialize the Json into an Object I get the following Error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name:
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'    at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor()    at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterCollection.CreateDefaultFormatters()
>   at
>   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.<>c__DisplayClass16.b__14(Task`1
>   task)
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed 
>   (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/XXXXXXXXX/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly :
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: No application configuration file found. LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG:
>   Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL file:///C:/Program
>   Files/XXXXXX/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL. WRN: Comparing the assembly name
>   resulted in the mismatch: Major Version ERR: Failed to complete setup
>   of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

This is how my app.config file looks like:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ApiUrl" value="http://localhost:56610/api" />
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Does anyone know why the configuration of Newtonsoft Json does not work and why the configuration I provided is not used?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for my problem.
My initial code was like the following:

```
        public DomainUser FindUserBySecurityIdentifier(SecurityIdentifier securityIdentifier)
    {
        var domainUser = new DomainUser(securityIdentifier.ToString());
        string domainUserJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(domainUser);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(domainUserJson);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        Exception exception = null;

        var item = DomainUser.EMPTY;
        var endpointUrl = ConstructEndpointUrl("api/FindUserBySecurityIdentifier");

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(endpointUrl))
        {
            Task postLink = HttpClient.PostAsync(endpointUrl, content).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    var response = task.Result;
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // The error occured at this line
                        item = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<DomainUser>().Result;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        exception = new Exception(response.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    exception = new Exception("The http request to the server did not run to completion. Please contact the administrator");
                }
            });
            postLink.Wait();
        }
        if (exception != null)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
        return item;
    }
```

After I changed my code like the following it finally works

```
        public DomainUser FindUserBySecurityIdentifier(SecurityIdentifier securityIdentifier)
    {
        var domainUser = new DomainUser(securityIdentifier.ToString());
        string domainUserJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(domainUser);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(domainUserJson);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        Exception exception = null;

        var item = DomainUser.EMPTY;
        var endpointUrl = ConstructEndpointUrl("api/FindUserBySecurityIdentifier");

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(endpointUrl))
        {
            Task postLink = HttpClient.PostAsync(endpointUrl, content).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    var response = task.Result;
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // after I read the result into a string first and deserialized it with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject it worked
                        var objectAsString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DomainUser>(objectAsString);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        exception = new Exception(response.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    exception = new Exception("The http request to the server did not run to completion. Please contact the administrator");
                }
            });
            postLink.Wait();
        }
        if (exception != null)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
        return item;
    }
```